# EXC_BAD_ACCESS executing block inside another block

Tags: ios, block, objective-c-blocks, exc-bad-access

I'm dealing with some legacy code which calls a chain of blocks inside one other. I randomly hit an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crash from time to time and I can't figure out why.

```
/

*
     Description: Submit type card transaction to MCM server.
     */
    - (void)submitTypeTransactionWithRequest:(ChargeRequest *)request completion:(void (^)(BOOL))completion {

        //login to gateway to begin transaction
        [self loginRoamServerWithCompletion:^(BOOL success) {
            if (success) {

                //make the payment
                Payment *responsePayment = [self makePayment];

                //if cvv is invalid, decline the transaction
                [self voidTxnWhenCVV2OrAVSInvalid:responsePayment completion:^(BOOL isValidCVV) {
                    if (completion) {
                        completion(isValidCVV);
                    }
                }];
            }
        }];
    }

    - (void)loginRoamServerWithCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL success))completion {
        ....

        [self rpxLogonSuccessfulWithCompletion:^(BOOL success) {
            if (completion) {
                completion(success);
            }
        }];
    }

- (void)voidTxnWhenCVV2OrAVSInvalid:(RpxPayment *)responsePayment completion:(void (^)(BOOL isValidCVV))completion {

        //This method is now called second time in the flow
        [self loginRoamServerWithCompletion:^(BOOL success) {
            if (success) {
               BOOL result = [self voidPayment];
               if (completion) {
                  completion(result);
               }
            }
        }];
    }
    - (void)rpxLogonSuccessfulWithCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL success))completion { 

     // at this point, when this method is called the second time => 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS'(completion = NULL)

        BOOL result = [self login]
        if (completion) {
           completion(result);
        }
    }
```

This is how the flow works. The first call is to `submitTypeTransactionWithRequest`. This then calls `loginRoamServerWithCompletion` which in turn calls `rpxLogonSuccessfulWithCompletion`. Once the transaction is done, `voidTxnWhenCVV2OrAVSInvalid` is called to invalidate the transaction if the CVV is invalid. This in turn calls `loginRoamServerWithCompletion` again which calls `rpxLogonSuccessfulWithCompletion`. When, `rpxLogonSuccessfulWithCompletion` is called for the second time, the code randomly crashes with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. The value of the `completion` block is NULL as per the stack trace.

[Attaching the stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Sron.png)

Comment: Looks to me like there are some weak references in there that are being unloaded when they're no longer referenced (garbage collected). Try changing them to strong references instead? Without seeing how those variables are being declared, impossible to tell for sure.

Comment: I haven't defined any of the completion blocks as properties or ivars. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: Nope, I'm talking about the other variables like `responsePayment` and `result`. Likely `result` is the one, since it's used in both places, and I can't see where it's declared.

Comment: Those are just local variables. I see the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on the method declaration `- (void)rpxLogonSuccessfulWithCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL success))completion`. Does that indicate the `completion` block is deallocated?

Comment: They're not local vars because you don't define them inside those voids. Unless you removed the declarations from your example?

Comment: Also it'll probably just crash on the entire completion block unless you put a breakpoint inside it.

Comment: Yes I removed the declarations in the example. Updated my original question to show them as local variables now

Comment: Ah, ok. Next best guess is that somewhere `rpxLogonSuccessfulWithCompletion` is being called without the completion block as a param, or a different structure. Search everywhere in your codebase that calls it and make sure it calls the completion block correctly. (Autocomplete helps here).

Comment: That's not the case either. Also even after putting a breakpoint inside the method, it crashes on the block declaration

Comment: Can such crashes also happen because the stack is too deep?

Comment: Not likely no. This is an error from trying to reference something that is deallocated or a mismatched header/implementation where the method doesn't exist.

Comment: A stack overflow caused by too many recursive block calls would show the same symptom, your call stack does not look like this though. But you seem to have a lot of threads running. Do all those threads possibly do the same thing (call the recursive block(s) mentioned in the question)?

Comment: No all the threads are not doing the same thing. But, I reduced the number of recursive calls and that seems to have fixed the issue for now. Thanks for your help!